# Similar method to apply when creating an object

Tags: javascript, function, object, arguments, apply

If I want to run a function within another function I can pass in some of the arguments like so:

```
function applyFunc(type) {
    myNamespace[type].apply(this, arguments.splice(1));
}
```

But is there a similar method (or really simple workaround) for instantiating a new object, i.e. pass the outer arguments into the inner function, but using the new keyword too?

```
function newObj(type) {
    new myNamespace[type].apply(this, arguments.splice(1)); //apply doesn't work here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should work. If it doesn't in your code, you may consider using `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1)` (or `[].slice.call(arguments,1)`) in stead of `arguments.splice(1)`. Here's some test code, also to be found in [this jsfiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/5maUx/):

```
function C(){}

C.prototype.fun = function(){
 alert('hello'+[].slice.call(arguments).join('\n'));
};

function newf(t){
 new C()[t].apply(this,[].slice.call(arguments,1));
}

new C().fun.apply(null,[1,2,3]); //works
newf('fun',1,2,3); //works
```